# Virtual hosts for MAMP 4.1.1 on MAC 10.12.6 not working

Tags: apache, mamp, virtualhost, vhosts

I know this has been asked hundreds of times and I made sure I read all of them, but still I cannot get this working. So as the title suggests, I cannot get a vhost running from MAMP/OSX. Here's a list of things I tried so far:

Created configuration in `/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /Applications/MAMP/htdocs
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/abcd/public"
    ServerName abcd.dev
    ServerAlias www.abcd.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

Removed comment from the line

```
Include /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

in the file `/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf`

Finally this is how my `/etc/hosts` file looks

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
fe80::1%lo0     localhost

127.0.0.1       abcd.dev
```

Restarted MAMP and here are the test results:

`http://localhost/` - Shows Index of and then `/abcd`

`http://127.0.0.1/` - Shows Index of and then `/abcd`

`abcd.dev` - Unable to connect, Firefox was unable to connect to the server abcd.dev

Surprisingly

`ping abcd.dev` - Returns response `64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.053 ms`

`ping 127.0.0.1` and `ping localhost` also returns same response.

I had docker running on my computer, I thought that was messing it up, so I stopped in completely, but the problem continues.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you have specified "www." prefix in your vhosts file, but tried to access is through abcd.dev (without the www.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`abcd.dev` is now officially a public domain. So basically my browser is trying to locate the site "out there".

Instead let's use something like `abcd.local` or `abcd.loc`

Hope this helps someone stuck in .dev labyrinth.

Answer (score 0):

you have specified "www." prefix in your vhosts file, but tried to access is through abcd.dev (without the www.)

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately when I try www.abcd.dev in the address bar it redirects to `https://www.abcd.dev/`. When I explicitly type `http://www.abcd.dev/`, it still redirects to the secure version and then says "Cannot find that site".

Checked on with Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Have you tried removing the www. From your vhosts file? ServerAlias abcd.dev then access http://abcd.dev